# How to use Mocha with Promises/ES6 generators?

Tags: javascript, node.js, ecmascript-6, mocha.js, chai

I want to use `Mocha` with `ES6 generators` and optionally with `expect`. After some research, I build the following code snippet:

```
describe('test', function() {
 it('should not work', function() {
  expect(function() {
    return co(function*() {
      yield Service.validate();
    });
  }).to.throw(new Error('error'));
 });
});
```

Service.validate throws `new Error('error')`, and thats what I `expect`.

```
module.exports = {
 validate: function() {
  return co(function*() {
   // use yield to access db and so on
   throw new Error('error');
  });
 }
};
```

However, the following code throws `AssertionError: expected [Function] to throw 'Error: error'`. Can anyone help?

Comment: If `Service.validate()` is promise-based and used exclusively within `co` wrapper, then the question concerns promises, not generators.

Comment: Updated the title...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`co` returns a promise, and errors thrown inside it will be turned into rejected Promises. So you have to test for a rejected Promise rather than an exception. This code works:

```
var chai = require("chai");
var chaiAsPromised = require("chai-as-promised");
var co = require("co");

var expect = chai.expect;
chai.use(chaiAsPromised); // Register chai-as-promised with Chai.

describe('test', function() {
 it('should not work', function() {
     return expect(co(function*() {
         throw new Error("testing failure!");
    })).to.be.rejectedWith(Error, "testing failure!");
 });
});
```

Note how this does `return expect(...)`. When you test promises with `expect`, it returns a promise, which can be returned to Mocha so that it can know when the test is over.

Answer (score 1):

[chai-as-promised](https://github.com/domenic/chai-as-promised) can be used in conjunction with `co`. `co` returns a promise, so it should be handled accordingly:

```
expect(co(function*() { ... })).to.be.rejectedWith(Error, 'error');
```

If the code isn't `co`-based, and the generator doesn't yield a promise, the generator `yield` may be tested directly:

```
expect(() => (function* () { ... })().next()).to.throw(Error, 'error');
```

Alternatively, [chai-generator](https://github.com/fengb/chai-generator) may be used instead for `to.yield` assertions.

Comment: `expect(...).to.be.rejectedWith` and `expect(...).to.throw` both require a constructor as their first argument. In your code here you pass `Error` instances instead of passing the constructor. (See [here](http://chaijs.com/api/bdd/#method_throw) and [here](https://github.com/domenic/chai-as-promised#shouldexpect-interface).)